# how to select a id and class attribute is active in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, class

i'd like to get data when the condition is id attribute is manufacture and class attribute is active.

my view :

```
    <li id="manufacture">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#faq-tab" id="warranty">Samsung</a>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="description_warranty" style="height: 400px;" rows="3" placeholder="Enter text . . . " >'+data[i].description_warranty+'</textarea>
    </li>
<li id="manufacture" class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#faq-tab" id="warranty">Apple </a>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="description_warranty" style="height: 400px;" rows="3" placeholder="Enter text . . . " >'+data[i].description_warranty+'</textarea>
    </li>
    <li><button data-toggle="tab" id="btnsaving" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
    <i class="White ace-icon fa fa-save bigger-130"></i>Save</button>
    </li>
```

Ajax Save() :

```
    var url;
    if($('#manufacture')) {
        url = "<?php echo base_url('admin-spot/company/AddBranch')?>";
    }else{
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
        $('.modal-title').text('WARNING!!!');//modal title
    }
```

any solutions, so when

class change to be active  i would create a function to save 
i just need to get data, if ( and ) and if yes run the other function, if no i show warning modal.

Comment: `id` and `class` of what element?

Comment: information is incomplete. Can you add the whole HTML mark up also id and class of which element with regards to the button click

Comment: i just need to get data,  if (<li id="manufacture"> and <li class="active">) and if yes run the other function, if no i show warning modal.